# gitlab push error: RPC failed; HTTP 524 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 524

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065172/clear-hiiden-large-files-in-gitlab-repo/70067140#70067140) about a way to clear 'hidden' large files in `gitlab` repo. I proceeded as follows:

Clone repo using `mirror` flag:

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/my-large-repo.git
```

Run the BFG to clean my repository:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M my-large-repo.git

$ cd my-large-repo.git
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
Enumerating objects: 1306, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1306/1306), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1238/1238), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1306/1306), done.
Building bitmaps: 100% (53/53), done.
Total 1306 (delta 242), reused 961 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

Everything seems to work at this point, but then I cannot push the clean `local` to `remote`.

```
$ git push
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': xxx@gmail.com
Password for 'https://xxx@gmail.com@gitlab.com': 
Enumerating objects: 1306, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1306/1306), 2.02 GiB | 16.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 1306 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1306
error: RPC failed; HTTP 524 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 524
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I am not sure why this keeps happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP 524 status code is specific to Cloudflare.  It indicates that a timeout occurred.  Like other 5xx codes, it indicates a problem with the server that the client cannot control.  Thus, there is nothing you can do to fix this.

You can either try again later, or contact GitLab about the problem.

Comment: See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/-/issues/8475  for information at GitLab about this topic.

Comment: having same problem, are you able to fix it?